# Show that if $a\neq b$, then we have for the $n\times n$-matrix $\textrm{det}=\frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

**The Problem**

Show that if $a\neq b$, then we have for the $n\times n$-matrix
$$\textrm{det}\begin{pmatrix} a+b & ab & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
1 & a+b & ab & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & a+b & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & a+b & ab \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & a+b\end{pmatrix} =\frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}$$
What if $a=b$?

---

**My Questions**

I am not entirely sure how to begin this proof.  I suspect I am missing something that makes it quite simple.  I tried looking for similar problems, and I noticed a common theme being the use of row operations to rewrite the matrix, from which the determinant was found.  However, I still didn't understand many of the intermediate computations when it came to actually finding the determinant.  My questions are as follows.

1. Should I use row operations to rewrite this matrix?  If so, what would be an example of how that would look computationally?
2. In either case, how should I go about actually computing the determinant to show the statement is true?  Is there an algorithm that is helpful here?
3. I noticed for the follow up question that, if $a=b$, then $$\textrm{det}\begin{pmatrix} a+a & aa & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
   1 & a+a & aa & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & a+a & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
   \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & a+a & aa \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & a+a\end{pmatrix}.$$  Am I right in my thinking there?

---

**Other Details**

The book used in the course is *Abstract Linear Algebra* by Curtis.  It has been of little help to me here...

Comment: I would try to prove it by induction using recursion.

Comment: Here's a hint for the second question: If you can prove the first question, what is $\lim_{b\to a}\frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b}$?

Comment: Show that $P_n=(a+b)P_{n-1}-a\,b\,P_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call $A_n$ the matrix for which you want to compute the determinant and let's see how it can be constructed iteratively:
$$ A_{n+1} = \begin{pmatrix} a+b & ab & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
1 & a+b & ab & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & a+b & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & a+b & ab \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & a+b\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}  
 A_n  &  \begin{matrix}  0 \\ \cdots \\ 0 \\ ab  \end{matrix} \\ 
 \begin{matrix} 0 & \cdots &  0 &  1 \end{matrix} & a+b
\end{pmatrix} $$

Such layout cries out for induction to compute the determinant $D_n = \det(A_n)$ . For $n=1$, we have $A_1 = (a+b)$ so $D_1 = a+b$ and $D_1 \cdot (a-b) = a^2 - b^2 $.

Now, if we assume the formula is true up to an integer $n$, can we prove that it is also true for $n+1$ ?

We can use  [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) applied to the last column to find out that:
$$ D_{n+1} = (a+b)\cdot D_n - ab \cdot D_{n-1}$$

Therefore:
$$ \begin{align} (a-b)\cdot D_{n+1} & = (a+b)\cdot (a-b) D_n - ab \cdot(a-b) D_{n-1} \\
& = (a+b)\cdot( a^{n+1} - b^{n+1} ) - ab \cdot( a^{n} - b^{n} ) \\
& = a^{n+2}- ab^{n+1} + ba^{n+1} - b^{n+2} - ba^{n+1}+  ab^{n+1}  \\
& = a^{n+2}- b^{n+2}\\
\end{align}  $$

And we are done for the first question.

The second question asks what is happening when $a=b$. Obviously we can't apply the formula above since it is only valid for $a \ne b $. But we can take $b$ as close as we want to $a$, let's say $b_k = a + \frac{1}{k}$. Now we can apply the previous result, meaning that for all positive integer $k$:
$$ \det \begin{pmatrix} a+(a + \frac{1}{k}) & a(a + \frac{1}{k})  & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
1 & a+(a + \frac{1}{k}) & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 &  \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
0 & 0  & \ldots & a+(a + \frac{1}{k}) & a(a + \frac{1}{k}) \\
0 & 0  & \ldots & 1 & a+(a + \frac{1}{k})\end{pmatrix} = \frac{\left(a + \frac{1}{k}\right)^{n+1} - a^{n+1}}{ \frac{1}{k} }  $$

To conclude, you can use the continuity of the determinant and take the limit on both sides as $k \to \infty $. On the left you have the determinant of the matrix $A_n$ with $a=b$ and on the right you have the derivative of the function $ x \mapsto  x^{n+1} $ at $x=a$, which is $(n+1)a^n$.

Comment: One can say that such a method (second order recurrence relationship on Dn) is general for tridiagonal matrices like this on, under the condition that they are Toeplitz.

Answer (score 3):

Let $L=\pmatrix{1\\ 1&\ddots\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&1&1}$ and treat $a$ and $b$ as two indeterminates. Then the matrix in question is equal to $A=D^{-1}(aL+bL^T)D$, where $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,a,a^2,\ldots,a^{n-1})$. Since $\det L=1$, we get
\begin{align}
\det A&=\det(aL+bL^T)
=\det\left(aI+bL^TL^{-1}\right)\\
&=(-b)^n\det\left(-\frac abI-L^TL^{-1}\right)
=(-b)^nf\left(-\frac ab\right),\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $f(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $L^TL^{-1}$. Now, if you calculate $L^TL^{-1}$ directly, you will see that it is the [transpose of a companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix#Linear_recursive_sequences). Hence you may read off the coefficients of $f$ directly from the entries of $L^TL^{-1}$. Then, using $(1)$, you should find that
$$
\det A=(-b)^nf(-a/b)=a^n+a^{n-1}b+\cdots+ab^{n-1}+b^n.\tag{2}
$$
Now the rest are straightforward when the indeterminates $a,b$ are specialised to two numbers.